# MYSQL database - How to work with an "order" column that stores the order items should be displayed - grouped by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-structures

This could by an x/y problem, so if there's a better approach altogether, I'd love to hear it. The summary of the problem starts at the last code block, so skip to that if you want and come back to the details if needed.

I am building a content manager (if nothing else, for the experience). To get started understanding what data I need, I made a "pages" table with this structure:

```
id (page id) | path (where it is found) | title | content  | (etc.. some other stuff)
```

So, it is the content area that is trouble. Let me explain the end result: I need a content map that has an object of positions, each which are arrays of content that belongs in that position. Here's a sample:

```
{ header: [5], main: [4,1], footer: [2,8,9] }
```

Those id's will then go to a content table, pull each item (like id 5) and replace the id with the actual content/settings for that item. That isn't really as relevant for now.

I can't just store the json right to the db in the content field of "pages" because if I were to delete content item "5", it would still be in the json for that page. I need to be able to delete content item 5, and it automatically be removed from wherever it is used.

That lead me to this:

I create another table that tracks where content items are used and the order. Here's the structure for that table (content_locations):

```
pageId (what page this content is on) | contentId (which content) | position | order
```

So, I think that gets me on the right track on being able to delete things... if I delete a page, I believe I can set it up to delete the rows it has in content_locations and also set it up so that removing a content item will remove the content_locations rows for that item. I honestly haven't tried that yet, but I'm pretty sure that's possible. If not, I'm really lost :)

My main issue seems to be the ordering. Consider this set of data:

```
pageId, contentId, position, order

2,      6,        header,   0
2,      1,        header,   1
2,      4,        header,   2
```

How could I insert a first item (can't insert before 0) or what if I wanted to insert in between one of those (1 1/2) or what if I deleted item 1? I run into a big problem with reordering. Is this a problem with my idea of how to structure the data, or is there a good solution for dealing with an ordering column such as that?

Comment: I don't even understand why you need a table for "pages". You can simply use the `LIMIT` operator and retrieve rows x to y without ever having to worry about page ordering.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I don't follow you. I look up the page according to the path the user is on. I need the page's general data - that's what the pages table is for. The other table is for the requested page's content, which should be displayed in a specific order that I need to know.

Comment: Then I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Imagine a page with two places where stuff can go. You need to know what page (pageId), what stuff you're putting on the page (contentId), which place you're putting it in (position) and where it is in that position (order). Like, if you were putting two items in the header, they would go in the order of 0,1. Add another items on the end, that would be order of 0,1,2. I'm asking how I would add an item at the beginning or in between...or what if I deleted say, the item that is ordered at "1".   Would I have to pull all those rows and manually update the orders??

Comment: well you can insert before 0, there negative 1, -2, -3 ,-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other issues notwithstanding, I'll just comment on reordering...

If you need to make space to insert a new row, you can easily move the other rows out of the way by:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET order = order + 1
WHERE pageId = ... AND order > 0
```

*(Replace 0 with the actual position at which you want to insert the new row.)*

You can do the opposite after delete, or you can just leave a hole - these holes can be easily "collapsed" at the presentation level.

Unless you have a large number of rows per page, this should be reasonably quick. If not, consider leaving holes in advance, and moving elements only if the hole is completely filled.

BTW, to switch two rows, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET order =
    CASE order 
    WHEN 2 THEN 3
    WHEN 3 THEN 2
    END
WHERE pageId = ... AND order IN (2, 3)
```

*(Replace 2 and 3 with actual positions.)*

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do this is to have an `after` column that references the pageId to say that this is after that. Although that's going to make for some complex SQL. Alternatively just start the order off as 0, 1000, 2000, which gives space to insert things.

One way to do the insert is to multiply every `order` value by two and add one -- this is a fairly trivial query. Then you have space to insert, so your table becomes:

```
pageId, contentId, position, order

2,      6,        header,   1
2,      1,        header,   3
2,      4,        header,   5
```

and then you just insert the order as `(order * 2)` and it's guaranteed to have a space.

Periodically you'll have to collapse the numbering in order to stop overflowing the values -- but if you check if there's a space beforehand then this should be rare. (You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to do the renumbering).

I wouldn't embed JSON in the database at all if you can avoid it, parse it and add it to separate tables to make your life easier later.